# Nest of compact set in $\sigma$-compact and locally compact space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be $\sigma$-compact and locally compact hausdorff space. There is a statement as follow:

$X$ $\sigma$-compact $\Rightarrow \exists\{K_n\}$ compact such that $X = \bigcup_{n \geq 1}K_n$  and it has following nest:
$$
K_1 \subset \mathring{K_2} \subset K_2 \subset \mathring{K_3} \subset K_3 \subset \cdots
$$
I can build a nest through $K_{2} = K_2 \cup K_1$ but what confusing me is how to show $K_1 \subset \mathring{K_2}$?

Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of $\sigma$-compactness? Because $\mathbb{Q}$ seems pretty $\sigma$-compact, but clearly does not satisfy the second property.

Comment: @Tyrone $\sigma$-compactness means that X can be expressed the countable union of compact subset of $X$.

Comment: Then I have have given an example above showing that the statement in your question is false.

Comment: @Tyrone Sorry. Your remined me. I loss the condition that $X$ is also a locally compact hausdorff space.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then your proof below seems correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

ok, I think I have find a way for construction.

$X$ is $\sigma$-compact, hence $\exists$ a sequence of compact set such that $\cup_nK_n = X$.

Take $K_1$ out from that. We can find a collection of compact set $\{V_x \vert x \in K_1\}$ such that $K_1 \subset \cup_{x \in K_1} V_x$ as $X$ is $\sigma$-compact. It is obvious that $\{\mathring{V_x}\}_{x \in K_1}$ is an open cover of $K_1$. By compactness of $K_1$, there exists an finite open cover $\{\mathring{V}_{x_i}\}_{i=1}^n$, that is
$$
K_1 \subset \cup_{i=1}^n\mathring{V}_{x_i}
$$
Furthermore, we have
$$
K_1 \subset \cup_{i=1}^n\mathring{V}_{x_i} \subset \cup_{i=1}^n\mathring{V}_{x_i} \cup \mathring{K}_2 \subset {(\cup_{i=1}^nV_{x_i}\cup K_2)}^{\circ} := {\tilde{K}_2}^\circ \subset \tilde{K}_2
$$
Notice that $\tilde{K}_2 := \cup_{i=1}^nV_{x_i}\cup K_2$ is finite union of compact set, which is compact.

Apart from that, $X = \cup_n K_n \subset \cup_n\tilde{K}_n$.

Comment: Minor comment. Choose $\{V_x\mid x\in K_1\}$ so that $K_1\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in K_1}V_x^\circ$. *Then* it is obvious that $\{V_x^\circ\}_{x\in K_1}$ coverse $K_1$.

Comment: It is not obvious, and possibly false, that $\{\mathring{V_x}\}_{x \in K_1}$ is a cover of $K_1.$ For example if $X=\Bbb R$ and $K_1=\{0\}=V_0.$ You should say $x\in U_x$ where $U_x$ is open and $\overline U_x=V_x$ is compact, which is possible because $X$ is locally-compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't know what is the definition of locally compact  space in your opinion. it is defined that a topological space is locally compact if there is a compact neighborhood for every point in it In my textbook.  Thus above $V_x$ is a compact neighborhood of $x \in K_1$. The definition of neighborhood tells us there is an open set $U_x$ such that $x \in U_x \subset V_x$, which implies that $x \in \mathring{V}_x$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  I'm sorry for causing such ambiguity because of loss strict statement.

Comment: Your textbook def'n of locally compact is standard. For a Hausdorff space it is equivalent that every point has an $open$ nbhd whose closure is compact.